# Visual Studio Ultimate running very slow :(

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio Professional to Ultimate.
The upgrade process worked perfectly and it ran fine for two days however the following operations are now exceedingly slow (2-3 minutes of 100% cpu)

- start a new app in debug,
- clicking ok to change options in visual studio
- ending a debug

any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

other info

- I'm on Win 7 Home Premium
- it's not related to compile speed - i can clean and rebuild without problem
- i've disabled intellitrace.

**update** - i've tried a few other projects i have lying around but it's only slow with the one i work on all day every day.

things tried:

- rename settings file
- start in /safemode

looking in process monitor i've spoted that after the long wait on ending a debug session i get several Name Not Found events to things like (last string changes)

KCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\ToolWindows{9F3EC988-1174-4746-A66A-3969715D1FC7}

on starting a debug session the last thing before the debug session is a few hundred writes/reads to

C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Design_tzss3kfu.pzf.winprf

then a minute later i get an access to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\cpde.dll

& finally an access to

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\ToolWindows{9F3EC988-1174-4746-A66A-3969715D1FC7}

which is not found :(

Comment: How many extensions have you installed?  Try running in /safemode and see if it doesn't zip along.

Comment: just tried /safemode - getting the same 2-3 min of 100% cpu when i hit run :(

Comment: Try analyzing the problem using Process Monitor / Process Explorer to see what is actually slowing things down.

Comment: You can't get 100% cpu with 4 cores on these operations.  Dust bunnies maybe: http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-029908.htm

Comment: I have looked with process explorer but cant spot anything, although i've heard of process monitor i've not used it - do you know of a how-to?

Comment: That you only experience the issues with one particular project/solution seems to point pretty strongly towards that being the culprit, rather than the development environment itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed the problem: 
using this: [Slow debugging issue in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio/590847#590847)

the .suo file in my project was some 15Mb, after deleting it it visual studio recreated it and it went down to 150Kb. & i can now start and stop debug sessions nigh on instantly.

Also the problem with setting options in tools options screen (took 2-3min) seems to have disappeared - this was happening even when i had no project open so i dont know how deleting a .suo file in one project would fix that?!

what should i do with this question? the answers above whilst helpful did not solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

On Windows XP and Vista machines, making sure Windows Automation API 3.0 is installed and running greatly helps performance (it helped my laptop).  Not sure if this applies to Windows 7 Home since it may already be installed.

[Windows Automation API 3.0 improves VS 2010 performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddperf/archive/2010/08/16/visual-studio-2010-runs-faster-when-the-windows-automation-api-3-0-is-installed.aspx)

Comment: from link: "Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 ships with with Windows Automation API 3.0, so no upgrade is required."

Comment: in 2016, the company I am doing a short job for STILL uses XP, VS 2010, and the link to download this WA API is unsurprisingly dead.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen when VS tries to connect to an external server.

- Disable Source Server under Options, Debugging
- Clear all servers from the Server Explorer window

If that doesn't help, start a second copy of VS and attach its debugger to the first one.
When it freezes, pause it in the second copy and look at the call stack.
This will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the the setting file in your My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings is partially currpted. You can rename this file CurrentSettings.vssettings and it will recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade your development machine. What are the stats? Visual Studio, although it's a wonderful wonderful IDE, it tends to eat resources like the cookie monster.

**Edit**
If you're compiling the same projects/solution often, have you tried doing a clean build and then running? Not sure if that's your issue but it's something else you could try.

Comment: Running on a HP laptop with 4GbRam & an core i7 Q720 (quad core with hyperthreading) @ 1.60Ghz. since its not the compilation running slow i dont think resources are a problem

Comment: thanks for the edit, as per question i can clean & rebuild almost instantly its only on starting/ending a debug sesson or on setting the options of visual studio that i hit problems :(

Answer (score 0):

there are may be many thing slow down your PC.

How many addons you have in your IDE

if this is not a problem then don't try  Windows Automation API 3.0 improves VS 2010 performance because you already have window 7 you descibed.

try to run them in safe mode that it may work well.

you can try many utilities to check where i am going wrong some are here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx

if you use original Visual studio 2010 then  you can contact Microsoft Fixit or Microsoft connect and also Asp.net forums

i thing your setting could not be set properly so create a new admin user delete the old and use with new and you feel that your visual studio Run very fast then last try this and feel make happy