# Visual Studio 2010 long debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow debugging issue in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio)

Hello,

I have a problem with vs2010, when i start debugging it works slow. Internet explorer opens but website loads extremely slowly. I stopped my anti-virus program but it couldn't be resolved. My workmate and me work on the same project and he doesn't have any problem like that. My hardware is 4G memory + Intel Core i5 CPU 3.20 GHz.

Comment: Not really a programming question IMO...

Comment: Is it SharePoint by any chance?

Comment: Not a programming question? Really? Because real programmers don't debug?

Comment: I agree with @Pontus, debug is essential part of programming..

Comment: This is of course not a programming question, as the slowness can be caused by another thing. I recommend @s.esin open a support case with Microsoft via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Perhaps others may have noticed similar problems with these not-too-uncommon programming tools? But, no, you're right: better to go through the backlog of SO questions where something non-programming-related **might** be the cause and close 'em off!

Comment: The reason it was closed as not a real question is because: *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*  Let's review: OP cannot debug. He wants us to figure out why he can't seemingly debug; but we don't have nearly enough information to be able to do little more than shoot blanks in the dark.

Comment: I'd close as too localized, but apparently lots of people want to play "Guess what's in the box."  Frankly, the answer is that this guy has got an assload of extensions running, some of which are behaving badly.  He needs to run VS in safe mode, then try to debug, and gaze in wonder at how much faster everything is.

Comment: @George major part of the questions fall in this category, that's how it works with newbies, people who English isn't their native language or people that just don't know how to ask. If all those questions will be closed, it's the end of SO. This specific question is very clear: debug is working slow. What might slow it down?

Answer (score 2):

Have you by any chance turned on IntelliTrace event and call information collection?  If not, do you also see slow debugging for non-web projects?

Comment: "Enable Intellitrance" checked also "IntellıTrance events only". Normally i do only web projects but i tried with non-web projects and there is no problem. It works well

Comment: Is the web application slow when run without an attached debugger?

Comment: i started without debugging, it is better, not slow

Comment: What happens if you debug with IntelliTrace disabled?

Comment: I tried when IntelliTrance disabled and enabled. Its same

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the [Proces Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) tool from Sysinternals to see whats really delay your system. When you run it, open also the **CPU History** on the Colums.

Using this tool you can get the view of whats goin on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug your web application with another browser? Try using Firefox or Chrome and see if it is still slow.

Comment: I tried with opera,firefox and chrome and stuation same. It takes long time.