# unusual long execution time in different context

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have unusual problem with my code.

I have a function that get tree from db (used recursive algorithm)

```
private RCLinks GetStructureCore(RC rc)
    {
        var model = new RCLinks(rc);
        using (var unit = UnitOfWork.Create(_dbsession))
        {
            var rcRepo = unit.GetRepository<RC>();
            var rcLinkRepo = unit.GetRepository<RCLink>();
            List<RCLinks> internal_structure = rcLinkRepo.GetAllWhere(x => x.RC_ID == rc.Id).Select(x =>
                {
                    var tmp_rc = rcRepo.Get(x.ToRC_ID);
                    return GetStructureCore(tmp_rc);
                }).ToList();
           model.InternalStructure = internal_structure;
           Log.Debug("End GS " + rc.Id);
        }
        return model;
    }
```

And when I call this function from UI thread, it executed 30-35 seconds,
but when I call it from UnitTest, execution time 1-2 seconds!

Below a part of code how I call function from UI thread and UnitTest

```
      DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
      var model = GetStructureCore(rc);
      DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
      Log.Debug("ExecTime= "+(end-begin).ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
```

why is it? Can I fix execution time in UI?

---

### PS

Sory,I Not correctly ask question. The slow time in Debug-mode only. on no-debug (Ctrl+F5) mode execution time are same as test-time.
I followed instructions [NHibernate: Criteria query slow in web app but fast in unit tests, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777561/nhibernate-criteria-query-slow-in-web-app-but-fast-in-unit-tests-why) and [Slow debugging issue in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio), but time in debug are same huge.

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to tell for anyone here. You will have to break it down and measure parts of it, follow the calls etc, to find the particular place where time is spent.

Comment: I try to measure each line of code use same DB and same entities in tree.In the UI context loading time of data from the database much longer.  I'm confused. I could not find the cause.
NHibernate repository support lazy loading of data. but i serialize my tree to json string in each context of testing. Results aren't changed.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a fundamental flow in your code, which is each time you do the recursion a unit of work created, within the previous unit of work. This could result in locking up database tables when you access data, I would change the code to,

```
    private RCLinks GetStructureCore(RC rc, UnitOfWork uow)
    {
        var model = new RCLinks(rc);
        var rcRepo = unit.GetRepository<RC>();
            var rcLinkRepo = unit.GetRepository<RCLink>();
            List<RCLinks> internal_structure = rcLinkRepo.GetAllWhere(x => x.RC_ID == rc.Id).Select(x =>
                {
                    var tmp_rc = rcRepo.Get(x.ToRC_ID);
                    return GetStructureCore(tmp_rc,uow);
                }).ToList();
           model.InternalStructure = internal_structure;
           Log.Debug("End GS " + rc.Id);

        return model;
    }
```

So the unit of work passed to the method and all the recursive operations done in the same unit of work,