# Does "Show Threads in Source" button do anything in VC# 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The Visual C# 2010 **Express** edition has a "Show Threads in Source" button.  It's enabled, changes state when you click it, etc, but it doesn't seem to do anything.   Hovering in the margin does not produce any thread information in tooltips when its pressed.

I was looking for a way to debug "The process or thread has changed since the last step" messages I get sometimes while debugging.   VC# Express doesn't seem to have a Threads Window.  How do you see what thread you're in while debugging in Express?

Answer (score 5):

It provides additional debugging information when working with multithreaded applications and must be activated before the start of the debugging session.

> When this option is turned on you get some very nice visual indicators
>   to show information about your threads. If you look carefully, you
>   will see that the breakpoint symbol actually has a red and blue
>   squiggly line through it and, just below that you see a similar
>   marker. If you hover the mouse over the threads marker you will see a
>   debug tool tip that shows you all of the threads that are executing at
>   that location. If you notice there are also some source code lines
>   shaded in grey, which indicates that another thread is executing at
>   the same location.

Taken from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/02/14/visual-studio-2008-debugging-tricks-ndash-multi-threaded-debugging.aspx). Another "feature", at least if your're working with C++, is that it slows things down massively.

Comment: I agree with the last statement, and it's not only C++. Debugging a C# web app would take [~5s for each debugging step to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429863/69809), until I disabled this damned feature.