# ASP.NET, MVC, C# project in Visual Studio taking a very long time to launch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am testing an ASP.NET, MVC, C# project in Visual Studio, when I try to launch it, it is taking *forever* to come up. It is also taking *forever* to stop after I try to stop debugging.  Is there some tool or utility I can use to see where the hold up is?

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting .suo file

Comment: Is your project hosted in IIS or local Visual studio intergrated IIS?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/590847/137615. I used this solution and it helped me.

Comment: Hey Jeroen, I'm not sure how to tell the difference for what you ask. Could you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: If your url  looks something like this when you're debugging `http://localhost:52578/` you're probably using the built-in Cassini web server from VS. If you've set up IIS Express on your machine and configured VS to use it then you're using "local Visual Studio integrated IIS", if you're hosting your application on a development server running IIS that would be "hosted IIS"