# Why it takes so long to hit the breakpoint in VS?

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm trying to debug my C# application, but it takes so long(more than 10 mins sometimes) to hit my breakpoint after I attached my `exe` process to VS.

I checked the output console and found this being printed all the time.

```
 A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

If I didn't set the breakpoint, it works well.

**Update:**

If I add following snippet to the line I want to set a breakpoint, it's been hit quickly.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

And for this, I have to delete all of my breakpoints.

But this is not so convenient setting more breakpoints.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Try the solutions suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at it.

Comment: The version of VS might be helpful.

Comment: Which version do you think is the better one solving this?