# visual studio 2015 update 3 taking too long to debug on recent install.

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

having a tough time here. This is my first time installing visual studio 2015 update 3. Using Windows 10 and have plenty cpu and ram but debugging my solution takes 5-10 minutes. I installed it in developer mode and as an administrator. There are no errors in the solution but it seems like it's taking forever to connect to the local host. Ram only goes to about 400mb when the site appears but takes forever to get there. I have tried disabling diagnostic tools, code lens and lots of features which help a little. Was reading about enabling certain user right privileges but I installed with the same admin that Windows 10 initially set so I am not sure if I need to do more with those. (honestly I have not been able to locate the Local Policy User Right to confirm they are set correctly) Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio It helped people as recently as 2016 according to the comments.

Comment: @Jim23, Which kind of app did you really debugging? As far as I know, some settings would impact the debugging performance like the Visual studio hosting process in the project property, or the Symbols loaded under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols. You could disable "Microsoft Symbol Servers", debug it again. Or you could delete the .suo file for your solution, and then re-open your project, debug it again.

Comment: thanks for the responses, it's an asp.net mvc 4 app

Comment: @Jim23, So it still has this issue now, am I right? Please visit the output windows during you debug your app, so you could get some messages which may help us know that what the VS debugging tool was doing. Not very sure tht why you set the IE as the default browser, but you could set different browser as the default one, and then debug it again, at least, we could know that whether it was related to the browser itself.

Comment: @Jim23, What about this issue? Would you please share me the latest information about it? How about using different browsers?